# Custom Back Navigation operation

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

i need a help

my app is Tab & navigation based.

in the navigation model i have a section to get input from user and store it to SQLLite thats working fine when i clicking the "save" button

prob here is once its saved i need to navigate user to the preveios level of the navigation controller (same operation like Navigation Back button).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [popViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```